# Error when putting file on hadoop file system in cdh

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, hadoop-streaming, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to put my 5 GB training dataset to hadoop file system of Cloudera cdh, but its not allowing me to put it on hadoop fs. The following errors occurs when running the put command :

```
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/cloudera/newtrain.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1447)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:569)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:440)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1980)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1409)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1362)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1260)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:525)
put: File /user/cloudera/newtrain.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

The following are the statistics of my VM :

```
Configured Capacity: 31244361728 (29.10 GB)
Present Capacity: 4739334144 (4.41 GB)
DFS Remaining: 2359943168 (2.20 GB)
DFS Used: 2379390976 (2.22 GB)
DFS Used%: 50.21%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 127.0.0.1:50010 (quickstart.cloudera)
Hostname: quickstart.cloudera
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 31244361728 (29.10 GB)
DFS Used: 2379390976 (2.22 GB)
Non DFS Used: 26505027584 (24.68 GB)
DFS Remaining: 2359943168 (2.20 GB)
DFS Used%: 7.62%
DFS Remaining%: 7.55%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Last contact: Mon Dec 08 09:12:43 PST 2014
```

so what I have understood is that it is because of less space in the hadoop hdfs , so if it is correct then can anyone let me the solution for increasing the size of my hadoop hdfs drive ?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use the virtual machine software (e.g. VirtualBox) to expand the size of the virtual machine's disk.

Comment: That's a different question, which seems to have been answered many times on the sister site Superuser, such as: http://superuser.com/questions/755683/how-to-resize-virtualbox-disk